# postgres_fdw extension not interpreting right data types

Tags: postgresql, postgres-fdw

I'm trying to gather some experience with ETL processes and for this reason I'm looking for ways to transfer data from one place to the other. Right now, I want to get a better hang of the postgres_fdw extension, because, if I understood it correctly, it allows me to import a whole schema with a single command.

```
IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA "public"
    FROM SERVER dvdrental into "public";
```

I already followed the whole documentation with installing and using the fwd extension and manual import from other tables worked fine. However, when I try this "bulk import", for one particular table I get the following error:

```
ERROR:  type "public.year" does not exist
LINE 5:   release_year public.year OPTIONS (column_name 'release_yea...
                       ^
QUERY:  CREATE FOREIGN TABLE film (
  film_id integer OPTIONS (column_name 'film_id') NOT NULL,
  title character varying(255) OPTIONS (column_name 'title') COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
  description text OPTIONS (column_name 'description') COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  release_year public.year OPTIONS (column_name 'release_year'),
  language_id smallint OPTIONS (column_name 'language_id') NOT NULL,
  rental_duration smallint OPTIONS (column_name 'rental_duration') NOT NULL,
  rental_rate numeric(4,2) OPTIONS (column_name 'rental_rate') NOT NULL,
  length smallint OPTIONS (column_name 'length'),
  replacement_cost numeric(5,2) OPTIONS (column_name 'replacement_cost') NOT NULL,
  rating public.mpaa_rating OPTIONS (column_name 'rating'),
  last_update timestamp without time zone OPTIONS (column_name 'last_update') NOT NULL,
  special_features text[] OPTIONS (column_name 'special_features') COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
  fulltext tsvector OPTIONS (column_name 'fulltext') NOT NULL
) SERVER dvdrental
OPTIONS (schema_name 'public', table_name 'film');
CONTEXT:  importing foreign table "film"
SQL state: 42704
```

When I look at line 5, I get why postgres is throwing the error. It's trying to create the column release_year with the type public.year. However, that's not a valid type (like INTEGER) and therefore I get the error.

Still, how can I fix it? I mean, how can I override the data type that postgres is trying to set for this specific column?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Thanks! That did it for me. I had to also create the type mpaa_rating used by the film table, but other than this it worked fine. I'd politely ask you to write a more general response, so that I can mark it as an answer!

Answer (score 3):

The table `film` uses a domain for the `year` column and an enum for the `rating` column.

`IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA` only imports tables and views, so it doesn't import domains, enums and other things.

You need to create them manually before importing the schema.

```
CREATE TYPE public.mpaa_rating AS ENUM (
    'G',
    'PG',
    'PG-13',
    'R',
    'NC-17'
);

CREATE DOMAIN public.year AS integer
    CONSTRAINT year_check CHECK (((VALUE >= 1901) AND (VALUE <= 2155)));
```